# Docker doesn't resolve hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I need to know the hostnames (or ip addresses) of some container running on the same machine.
As I already commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269870/how-do-docker-containers-resolve-hostname-of-other-docker-containers-running-on/26274232#comment65923973_26274232) (but with no answer yet), I use `docker-compose`. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) says, compose will automatically create a hostname entry for all container defined in the same `docker-compose.yml` file:

> Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

But I can't see any host entry via `docker exec -it my_container tail -20 /etc/hosts`. 
I also tried to add `links` to my container, but nothing changed.

Comment: can you show docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Have you done some testing to find out if docker will resolve the other containers' hostnames? Or are you just enquiring about how to discover those hostnames?

Comment: The second thing. My containers are able to discover each other by their container-names.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Docker 1.10 introduced some new networking features](https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/docker-1-10/) which include an  [internal DNS server](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/767) where host lookups are done.

On the default bridge network (docker0), lookups continue to function via `/etc/hosts` as they use to. `/etc/resolv.conf` will point to your hosts resolvers.

On a user defined network, Docker will use the internal DNS server. `/etc/resolv.conf` will have an internal IP address for the Docker DNS server.  This setup allows bridge, custom and overlay networks to work in a similar fashion. So an overlay network on swarm will populate host data from across the swarm like a local bridge network would.

The "legacy" setup was maintained so the new networking features could be introduced without impacting existing setups.

#### Discovery

The DNS resolver is able to provide IP's for a docker compose service via the name of that service.

For example, with a `web` and `db` service defined, and the `db` service scaled to `3`, all `db` instances will resolve:

```
$ docker-compose run --rm web nslookup db

Name:      db
Address 1: 172.22.0.4 composenetworks_db_2.composenetworks_mynet
Address 2: 172.22.0.5 composenetworks_db_3.composenetworks_mynet
Address 3: 172.22.0.3 composenetworks_db_1.composenetworks_mynet
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the names of the available services running from within a container?  `docker-compose config --service` does this from the host but not within the container, and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` just shows `nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0`

Comment: You may want to run that with `--rm` or end up with a bunch of containers you don't want sticking around